# Angular 6 - Refused to apply style from '...' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet

Tags: reference, styles, angular6

Trying to upgrade to Angular 6 and got the below error when I referred the below in index.html:

Refused to apply style from 'https://localhost:44394/~/assets/primengcss/themes/omega//theme.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer (at least worked for me), after some digging around:

Looks like inAngular 6 we need to include any external CSS (like bootstrap, fontawesome, Primeng etc.,) to the angular.json as below:

```
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
          "src/styles.css",
          "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
          "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
          "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

Comment: I am seeing the error, but it's after running `ng b --prod` and the src/styles.scss is turned into styles.281397b30abd8baeff22.css. The latter file is not recognized. Should this solution handle that case?